# Ruby on Rails: question about validates_presence_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a relationship in my ActiveRecord based model that looks like:

```
belongs_to :foo
```

My model should always have foo defined in it for it to be valid. My question is, when using validates_presence of, which one is the appropriate one to use:

```
validates_presence_of :foo
```

or

```
validates_presence_of :foo_id
```

Assuming here of course, that foo_id is the appropriate foreign key, which it is by default if you do not change the association key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one: `validates_presence_of :foo` (though I think the second one will work too). In general the Ruby validation helpers work on model names as opposed to explicit column names. You can use this *in addition to* `validates_associated` to both validate the state of the associated entity in addition to its presence.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider `validates_associated`

This will make sure that the association is valid.

Comment: validates_associated and validates_presence_of are mutually exclusive if I'm not mistaking. I want to make sure that the associated object is a part of the model. by definition, it should be valid itself.

Comment: You need to use both validates_associated and validates_presence_of. See other comment for link to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I use `validates_presence_of :foo_id`. It works.