# Validation association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activemodel

I have two models: Location and User.  Location `has_many :users` and User `belongs_to :location`.  Now I have a form that uses something similar to:

```
 <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
 ...
   <%= f.select(:location,:location_id,Location.all.collect{|location| location.name}) %>
 ...
 <%end%>
```

When inspected it appears that it generates the correct form field for it:

```
 <select id="user_location_id" name="user[location_id]">
    <option value="Clearfield">Clearfield</option>
    <option value="San Diego">San Diego</option>
  </select>
```

According to [Ruby on Rails: question about validates_presence_of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755828/ruby-on-rails-question-about-validates-presence-of) validates_presence_of should work on the model name and in my models I have:

**User.rb:**

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :location
       validates_presence_of :location
   ...
```

**Location.rb:**

```
 class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :users    
 ...
```

What am I doing wrong that would make it so that `validates_presence_of` doesn't see location when I use `validates_presence_of :location`, but for some reason works when I use `location_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validates_presence_of :location` doesn't add error in following situation:

```
user = User.new(:location => Location.new)
user.valid? # => true
```

On the other hand, `validates_presence_of :location_id` doesn't add error if `location` with given `id` doesn't exist:

```
user = User.new(:location_id => 123)
user.valid? #=> true
Location.find_by_id(user.location_id) #=> nil
```

Comment: The ```validates_presence_of :location``` was a typo in the question and has been fixed.  You made a good point on your second.  Sounds like ```validates_associated``` to be included too.

Answer (score 0):

I got half-way through writing this question when I noticed my mistake, but in case it benefits someone else I've placed it here.

One may notice that the generated HTML that it isn't an integer that is in the value fields of the options.  It is the name.  Thus the piece of code having the problem is:

```
<%= f.select(:location,:location_id,Location.all.collect{|location| location.name}) %>
```

This is easy enough to fix, just add the id like so:

```
<%= f.select(:location,:location_id,Location.all.collect{|location| [location.name,location.id]}) %>
```

Once I did that the values became integers and upon submition of the form I know longer got an error stating that I needed to enter a value for location.